# Why glibc is so important for Linux, even for non C developers?

Tags: linux, glibc

I've read the Silberschatz's book "Operating systems" and I've seen many many questions on Stack Overflow but I can't really understand the importance of glibc for Linux.

I know that it is the GNU C standard library and that it contains standard functions (like `strcpy`) and wrapper functions for system calls.

What I can't understand is: if a developer doesn't use C language, which is the role of glibc? I think that in the compilation stage the compiler will produce assembly code that make use of glibc wrapper functions, regardless of whether the source code is written in C or in another programming language, but there is more? There are other reason that make glibc indispensable for Linux?

Comment: Maybe relevant https://www.reddit.com/r/copypasta/comments/6v2jgg/let_me_interject_for_a_moment/ .

Comment: (1) glibc is an implementation of libc, which is (roughly speaking) an abstract interface to standard C library functions plus POSIX functions. There are other implementations, though glibc is the most popular. (2) One does not need glibc (or some other implementation of libc) but it surely is convenient to have one. Even if you don't need the standard C library, you do need some kind of OS interface, and glibc provides one so could just as well use it.